# changing all n_0 value that is a char in a data set to a N_1 value that is a numeric value for the entire data set

Tags: sas

Suppose you import some file, and have the variables

```
name room# test1 test2 test3
```

and n observations.

The name is a name, the room number is a room number of length 3 and test1 - test3 are scored from 0 - 100.

```
name room# test1 test2 test3
bob  123   90    40     33
bob2 123   a     40     90 
bob3 123   88    k      78
..
```

Now, suppose I want to find all the instances of the letter `k` and replace them with a numeric value zero. How can this be done? I am doing this during the initial data step by using if then statement, i.e.

```
data temp;
   infile = "...." ; 
   if test1 = k then test1=0; 
   if test2 = k then test2=0; 
   if test3 = k then test3=0; 
run;
```

Is there a better way of doing this ?

Comment: If test1, test2, test3 are scored from 0 - 100 how can they be equal to k.  More importantly, are test1 text2 and text3 numeric or strings - they can't be both

Comment: 'k' would be an input for a testn if they were absent without an excuse and 'a' could be an input for testn if they were absent with an excuse.

Comment: so you want test1 test2 and test3 to be strings and not numeric?  You can do that but if you want to average your test scores you'll have to convert the strings to numeric.  Is that really what you want to do?  Why not use negative numbers like -99 and -10 to designate excuse or not excused

Comment: test1, test2, test3 are numeric. a letter 'k' or a letter 'a' are comments added to the file. i gues the proccess would be receiving a file .txt, csv ect importing into sas using the infile or proc import and changing all instances of a comment, which happens to be 1 letter in this case to a numeric value.

Comment: You can't do that.  The entire column needs to be a string or a numeric but not both.  You can't sometimes say a variable is numeric and other times it's a string.  Pick one and go from there.  I think my earlier response will be easier to implement but you can also treat the columns as strings and create new variables as numeric

Comment: @DCR I would read up on special missings - that's the SASsy way to do what you're describing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `informat` to do this.  I assign `.A` to `A` values, which is a special missing value (it will be treated as missing, but displayed as "A" not ".").  Informat is how you tell SAS what value a text string should have when read into a numeric field.

If you wanted to keep `A` and `K` both as "missing", by the way, you wouldn't need an informat; just `missing a k;` statement which tells SAS to treat those two characters as their special missing value when encountering in a normal numeric read-in.  But here you need the informat to treat them properly since you want `K` to be 0.

I would be tempted to suggest reading these both in as their special missing anyway, by the way, and treat the `K` like 0 later on when you're computing with it - converting to `0` right away loses information.

```
proc format;
invalue gradei
0-100 = [3.]
'a'   = .A
'k'   = 0
other = .
;
quit;

data want;
informat test1-test3 gradei.;
input name $ room $ test1 test2 test3;
datalines;
bob  123   90    40     33
bob2 123   a     40     90 
bob3 123   88    k      78
;;;;
run;
```

Comment: will wonders never cease. learn something new every day.  nice answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading from a text file then use the `MISSING` statement to let SAS know which letters you want it to allow you to read as meaning special missing values. So the letter `A` will become special missing value `.A`.

```
missing a k ;
data want;
  input name $ room $ test1 test2 test3;
datalines;
bob  123   90    40     33
bob2 123   a     40     90 
bob3 123   88    k      78
;;;;
```

Now if you want to convert your missing values to zero there are multiple postings on line for how to do that.

Comment: right,i might have asked my question incorrectly. i shall rephrase.